How to prevent R8 from removing code of 3rd party library uses in a flutter plugin?
I created a flutter plugin that uses in its android implementation:
        implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:8.0.4'
        implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.13'
        implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:2.0.13'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.2.0'
    }

I hosted it on github and depended on it in my pubspec.yaml in a flutter app.
When I run the app in debug mode it runs normally and the plugin works as expected.
If I try to run it in release mode, the code does not even compile, giving me alot of errors about missing classes:
[        ] ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /Users/haidarmehsen/Work/acksession/flutter/vsa-tablet/build/app/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt.
[        ] ERROR: R8: Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
[        ] Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 5 other contexts)
[        ] Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.<init>())
[        ] Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int))
[        ] Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int) and 4 other contexts)
[        ] Missing class org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$DisabledHostnameVerifier)
[        ] Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List))
[        ] Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
[        ] Missing class org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.<init>())
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

if I go to the missing rules file indicated in the error log, I find this file:
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier
-dontwarn org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters
-dontwarn org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
-dontwarn org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE

Now we come to what I tried:

First obviously the error's suggestion => result: the app compiles, but since I only suppressed the warnings, the plugin code throws errors at runtime.
Tried defining a proguargd file, referencing it in build.gradle, and using the -keep to keep the classes, also used wildcard patterns to keep everything, but did not work, same error kept happening:

-keep class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters { *; }
-keep class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket { *; }
-keep class org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider { *; }
-keep class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version { *; }
-keep class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt { *; }
-keep class org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier { *; }
-keep class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters { *; }
-keep class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket { *; }
-keep class org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE { *; }


Finally used the last resort which is, in my app (not the plugin), I disabled the R8 completely by using         release { signingConfig signingConfigs.release minifyEnabled false shrinkResources false }
this works but is not recommended and it also doubles my app size.

Can you help me solve this error without disabling shrinking of everything?

When you get missing classes warnings, then the classes are actually missing on input (R8 cannot see them when preforming whole program optimization). Adding -dontwarn silence these warnings but otherwise change nothing. Adding a -keep for these classes has no effect, as they are not present in the first place.

@sgjesse if they are not present in the first place, then why does the app work normally when the shrinker is disabled? And do you know what I should do to fix this (or where can I read about this particular case)?

If turning on R8 makes the app fail at runtime, then it could be from missing keep rules for items used by reflection, and potentially unrelated to the missing classes. You should analyze the crashes you get after building with the dontwarn to see if you can figure out what is wrong woth the app in the release build.
